# How to define an 'It' test for a nested function in Pester 5?

Tags: powershell, pester, pester-5

Given a PowerShell script (.ps1) with functions and nested functions. The function 'Inner' should not be moved to the outer scope and thus not be exported. How can one **define an 'It' test for the 'Inner' function** (hopefully without modifying the code)?

Using: PS core 7.1.4:

```
Function Outer {
    Function Inner {
        # ...
    }
    # ...
}
```

Using: Pester 5.3.0:

```
Describe "A" {
    It "A" { Outer } | Should -be $null  # OK
    It "B" { Inner } | Should -be $null  # ERROR
}
```

Comment: `It "B" { { Inner } | Should -Throw }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, that's funny :) good answer, haha

Comment: It's not a joke. If you're expecting invocation of Inner to throw a CommandNotFoundException you really should test for that

Answer (score 0):

If you really must do this, there is a way but it involves searching through the abstract syntax tree. This might be a bit complex, but it does the job.

So you have the functions defined as such:

```
Function Outer {
    Function Inner {
        # ...
    }
    # ...
}
```

You can find the `scriptblock` of the `Inner` function as follows:

```
$outerCommandInfo = Get-Command -Name 'Outer'
$innerDefinition = $outerCommandInfo.ScriptBlock.Ast.FindAll( { param($ast) $ast -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] }, $true) | ? Name -eq 'Inner'
$innerScriptBlock = $innerDefinition.Body.GetScriptBlock()
```

Now, in the `$innerScriptBlock` variable you have the definition of the `Inner` function. You can invoke it using the [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) or simply `$innerScriptBlock.Invoke()`

It will be a little trickier to pass parameters and to test it.

```
Describe "A" {
    BeforeAll {
        # the code above
    }

    It "A" { Outer } | Should -be $null  # OK
    It "B" { & $innerScriptBlock } | Should -be $null  # OK?
}
```